# Different UI for iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

In my app I have browser and UI for iPad and iPhone should be different.
I don't use storyboards and write all programmatically.
Also, when user taps on "downloadsButton", there will be different behavior.
On iPhone a new controller with full screen size will appear from bottom, but on iPad a little square view will appear in the center of screen.
How can I do this properly ?

iPhone

[image]

iPad

[image]

Comment: If this is the basis of your design, I must say that it look slick. [This great tutorial about adaptive layout](https://www.raywenderlich.com/162311/adaptive-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started) might be good to have a look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you touch `downloadButton` to invoke `downloadAction`, then you may try to change the `modalPresentationStyle` (of the view controller you want to show) doing so:

```
func downloadAction() {
  let downloadVc = DownloadViewController()
  downloadVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? .formSheet : .fullScreen
  self.present(downloadVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: And what about building different UI like on pictures ? Should I also use UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ?

Comment: I do think if you want to write everything programmatically, you will have to use quite often such condition (`UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == ?`)